# Phrase or word to describe "failing to maintain a good habit, as life changes"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

> "Good habits may demand time, energy and willpower to keep. As life changes, people may no longer be able to maintain certain good habits which they used to be in."

I am looking for a concise expression, be it formal or informal, for this kind of a situation, where one can no longer keep up a good habit, which was once practiced, but has died out gradually.

Comment: I think there is a need for more clarification about what stopped the person from being the same person and what is the "good habits".

As a learner, I can only suggest the adjective "stale" which, however, means to lose the previous sharpness and creativity because of overdoing something or doing it for a long time. **I won't defend him because I think he's stale and isn't half the wrestler he once was. (From Oxford)** Again, this adjective works only if the reason is doing a task for a long time and the good habit is doing something well.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a bit awkward/stilted, and there's too much redundancy. It doesn't flow well.  I would word it differently. Perhaps something like this:

> Maintaining good habits takes some conscious effort, but as life
>   changes, these may fall by the wayside.

*to fall by the wayside*: means to fail to persist in an endeavour or undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

The word [lapse](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lapse) can be used both a as a verb or a noun. As a noun, it generally refers to a temporary failure, but as a verb it can be permanent. You can also use the past participle **lapsed** as an adjective. It can certainly refer to a gradual decline.

> It's great if you are a **lapsed** exerciser – it is so easy that you will mentally get back into the frame of mind without much effort, and your muscles won't have forgotten - [Healthy living: Life-boosting, stress-beating, age-busting ways to total health](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=PTOCBFNN7H8C&pg=PA20&dq=lapsed%20exercise&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGsped0NzYAhXFv7wKHZWSB2k4ChDoAQhXMAk#v=onepage&q=lapsed%20exercise&f=false)